# MYSQL - Count rounds

Tags: mysql, count, inner-join

I got this statement (so far) for a contest script:

```
SELECT COUNT(round) AS runden, COUNT(status) AS status FROM rounds AS r INNER JOIN player AS p ON r.playerID = p.id WHERE r.playerID = <ID>"
```

This table saves all played rounds by a certain user. 
If a user participates to a round, it will be written in this table:

id = id
playerId = Id of the player
round = the played round (from 1 to 4)
played = If the user played it = 1 if not = 0
status = If the user won this round = 1 if not = 0

Now what I need is to the value of all played round by status = 1 or status = 0. So I need the total won rounds and lost rounds.

This displays it:

```
function getRoundsByPlayer($playerId) {
        $sql = "
        SELECT COUNT(round) AS runden, COUNT(status) AS status FROM rounds AS r INNER JOIN player AS p ON r.playerID = p.id WHERE r.playerID = :playerId";
        try {
            $db = self::getConnection();
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam("playerId", $playerId);
            $stmt->execute();
            $player = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
            $db = null;
            return $player;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

$runden = $helper->getRoundsByPlayer($row['id']);
```

and HTML:

```
...  
<td><?php echo $runden->runden; ?></td>  
...
```

How do I implement it by not using a second or third SQL statement? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can use conditional count like this

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN r.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS won_rounds,
       SUM(CASE WHEN r.status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS lost_rounds
  FROM rounds AS r INNER JOIN 
       player AS p ON r.playerID = p.id 
 WHERE r.playerID = <ID> AND r.played = 1
 GROUP BY r.playerID
```

*The query has not been tested*

Answer (score 1):

Use the following SQL-statement (not tested):

```
SELECT SUM(played) AS played
       SUM(status) AS status
FROM rounds AS r
INNER JOIN player AS p
ON r.playerID = p.id
WHERE r.playerID = :playerId
GROUP BY r.playerID;
```

This should provide you with the following information:

> played = number of rounds played by the user
>   status = number of rounds won by the user

You can easily calculate the number of lost rounds by substracting the two.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. Some error is happening. But thanks. I see similarities to the answer of peterm which is working for me.